# Categorize large factor into small factors based on frequency with remaining entries as 'Others'

Tags: r

I have a large factor (df$name) with more than 1000 factors. What I need is the top 10-15 factors by frequency and the remaining factors clubbed together as 'others'

I tried using the following command but wasn't successful:
df$name <- levels(df$name)[which(table(df$name)<1000000)] <- "Others"

PS: I'm using a frequency count since I don't want to restrict myself with a specific count of factors here. I'm happy if I get anywhere from 5-20 top factors (by frequency) and the rest of them combined together as 'Others' for easy visualization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would count name frequency by using `table()` & `top_n()` to specify top 15 (or 10) names in your data set. (I contained them in `top_15_names` object.) After that I did create `name_category` column to show groups of names by using `mutate()`. Here is how I would do it.

```
df$name = as.factor(df$name)
top_15 = data.frame(table(df$name)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Freq)) %>% 
  top_n(15)
top_15_names = top_15$Var1

dat = df %>% 
  mutate(name_category = case_when(
    name %in%  top_15_names ~ "Top15",
    TRUE ~ "Others"
  ))
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hey!
I understand your algorithm and it seems very sensible. Though, I wasn't able to work it out perfectly.
Can you explain why did you use 'dat' for. Is that a new dataframe to store the categories?
I would like a new variable in the previous dataset so I tried using df$names_cat instead of 'dat' and it didn't work.

Comment: absolutely, no need to store the new data into `dat`. I just thought it might be convenient to rename data frame with an entire new column. So it is up to you. And if you want to name a new column `names_cat`, then simply replace it for `name_category`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a column in a data frame with 2000 factors:

```
df <- data.frame(names = sample(1:2000, 1E6, replace = T))
df$names <- as.factor(df$names)
```

And here a new variable is added which keeps the top 15 and puts the rest in "Other."

```
df$names_lump = forcats::fct_lump(df$names, n = 15)
```